# Modelo User de django extendido en Django Rest Framework. Guardar un usuario vinculado al usuario logueado

Tags: django, djangorestframework

Es requerimiento del proyecto partir de una base de datos ya existente, en la cuál existe una tabla empleados que extiende el modelo User de django a través del campo usuarioweb.

Necesito crear un servicio que al guardar un pedido de venta guarde el empleado (idemplea) relacionado al usuario logueado. Hasta aquí solo usé vistas genéricas probablemente debería usar otras clases, agradecería si alguien puede orientarme sobre como lograr este comportamiento y que métodos tendría que sobre escribir.

No sé si sea relevante pero la autenticación es por token:  rest_framework_simplejwt

Sólo muestro algunos campos de los modelos a modo de ejemplo.

model.py

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Empleados(models.Model):
    idemplea = models.SmallIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    emplea = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    tipoemplea = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    usuariweb = models.ForeignKey(User, models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name="Usuario Web", blank=True, null=True) 

class Pedidosventas(models.Model):
    idpedidoventa = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    idemplea = models.ForeignKey(Empleados, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='idemplea')
    idempleaanulad = models.ForeignKey(Empleados, models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="pv_emplea_anulad", db_column='idempleaanulad', blank=True, null=True)
    idempleacerrad = models.ForeignKey(Empleados, models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="pv_emplea_cerrad", db_column='idempleacerrad', blank=True, null=True)
```

serializers.py

```py
class EmpleadosSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Empleados
        fields='__all__'    


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields=('username', 'password') 
        extra_kwargs={ 'password': { 'write_only':True } }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User( username =  validated_data['username'] )  
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user

class PedidosventasSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    nombrefantas = CuentasclientesSerializer(source='idcuentaclient', read_only=True)
    emplea = EmpleadosSerializer(source='idemplea', read_only=True)
    empleacerrad = EmpleadosSerializer(source='idempleacerrad', read_only=True)
    empleaanulad = EmpleadosSerializer(source='idempleaanulad', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Pedidosventas
        fields='__all__'
```

apiviews.py

```py
class PedidosventasList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Pedidosventas.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PedidosventasSerializer

class PedidosventasDetalle(generics.RetrieveDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Pedidosventas.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PedidosventasSerializer    

class PedidosventasUpdate(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Pedidosventas.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PedidosventasSerializer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logre guardar el campo que necesitaba de la siguiente manera:

```py
class PedidosventasList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Pedidosventas.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PedidosventasSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        idemplea = Empleados.objects.get(usuariweb = self.request.user)
        serializer.save(idemplea=idemplea)
```

Lo comparto por si a alguien le sirve o por si hay una mejor forma de hacerlo que me puedan indicar. Gracias!